# Not able to build menus in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I've installed a free Elementor builder site. I'm trying to add a menu, but when I drag and drop the WP Menu widget onto the module, it shows no menu list to select from:

[image]

I've searched online and YouTube to figure out how to build a menu. The tutorials I've come across either don't align with what I have, ie.

1. Click on Menus under the Appearance main menu on the WP dashboard. ME: {frustrated} There is no menu option under Appearance.
2. Create a new navigation menu under Appearance -> Editor by clicking the '+' icon. ME: {frustrated} There is no '+' icon, even when I click on navigation. When I click on navigation, it just lists pages

[image]
[image]

3. And even though this menu displays in the editor, as one can see on the first image, it still doesn't display on the menu list.

If anyone has any tutorial, video or otherwise, on how to build a menu using the theme and/or block style WP, please let me know.

All I want is a menu. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I needed. I just need to add the following php code into my functions.php file:

add_theme_support( 'menus' );

From there, the Menu option appears in the Appearance menu and then I can build my menu; which, in turn, appears in my builder.

[image]